# On-demand virus scanning Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, virus, windows-server-2008-r2, virus-scanning

I'm wanting to scan files a user uploads to our websites on the server-side. I'd prefer it to be something we can run on-demand that doesn't have to be running all the time on the server. What solutions are available for Windows Server 2008 R2? Which products specifically would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your situation, I would script up a solution to call [ClaimAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/about/win32/) on the file, whenever you receive the file. For Windows, if you are running IIS, (or any web framework) there is probably some sort of callback on file reception you can plug this into.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the antivirus programs provide you a command-line version (or starting parameters) to scan just one file, or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are several scanners on demand, there is a list named "Probably the Best Free Security List in the World" which lists a few, sorry I cannot provide the link because StackOverflow limits the amount of hyperlinks new users can post.

Although not listed in that list, one of the best I've used is the F-Prot Antivirus and it seems it runs well in Windows Server 2008

https://forum.f-prot.com/index.php?topic=1691.0

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For your case the best solution would be using http://www.virustotal.com/